# AMD Raid (RaidXpert) and expanding RAID 1 logical drives

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid, hardware-raid

Here's the setup. I've got an old machine with basic RAID 1 arrays.

Basically, 4 physical drives were used to create 2 logical drivers in RAID 1, each filled to the brim. Also, the machine is running Windows (the OS is also part of the RAID).

I've wanted to expand the available storage. I've got 4 new, bigger drives. A friend of mine told me it's as simple as replacing one drive of a RAID 1 pair, waiting for the array to rebuild, then the other. And I did exactly that.

The end result is that the logical drive takes up 1/3rd of the available space (on all physical drives). I am, however, unable to resize said logical drive. Windows doesn't see the physical drive (and can't tell there's free space), while the RAID software (both the BIOS utility and the RAIDXpert utility) doesn't seem to offer an expand feature (the phrase seems to appear here and there, but is always greyed out).

Here are some screenshots from AMD RaidXpert regarding the current configuration:

[image: Drive view]
[image: Drive view]
Note that I've already created an additional RAID 1 logical drive on the larger disk pair. I tried to see if I could perhaps merge it with the existing disk...

I COULD back up all the data from one of the logical drives to some external storage, delete the logical drive and recreate it with a larger size. BUT what about the drive where the OS is stored? I can't just copy that over (or at least not in any easy way).

Does anyone know what to do with that kind of RAID controller and how to expand the RAID 1 logical drives so they take up all the available space?

Answer (score 0):

If you have RaidXpert updated and the option is still grayed out, it means that you cannot expand that type of array in the manner you desire. Bet thing for you would be to use the old drives and single drives, transfer the data there, build the new RAID, transfer the data back. If you also want to upgrade the OS drive, install the OS on a new drive and then proceed as I said. It is currently unclear if the OS is on a separate drive or part of the RAID system (as partition).

Comment: I could try installing a newer version, sure... but this is an old motherboard, so I'm not sure this is a valid option. I'm pretty sure expanding SHOULD be possible simply because this is a very simple case (RAID 1 with 2 identical drives should allow for the logical disk to be expanded). I've also modified the question to include information about the OS (it's part of the RAID).